# how to define type of :style object vue3 typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

In the template I have:

```
 <template>
      <div ref="PopupContent" class="popupContent" :style="data.contentStyle">
 </template>
```

In setup I have:

```
export default defineComponent({
    name: "Popup",
    setup() {
       const data = ref({
       someOtherProp: 0,
       style: <StyleValue>(),
       someOtherOtherProp: false,
       retries: 0,
    });
```

I can also define some objects as interfaces if I need to, but perhaps there is an existing type that can be used. I still don't know the correct syntax for the setup to do this.

```
interface StyleProps {
   left: string;
   right: string;
   top: string;
   bottom: string;
   width: string;
   height?: string;
}
```

If I do this, is there a great way to make these accessible to all of the code that uses them?

I'm trying to find a way to define style that doesn't have problems later in the code trying to set **this.data.style["width"]**, for example.

So in response to one of the answers, this seems to work, but I have a further question:

```
const style: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {};
const arrowStyle: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> = {};

const data = ref({
   strokeWidth: 0.108,
   style: style,
   arrowStyle: arrowStyle,
});
```

Is there a way to do this inline on defining **const data** rather than the awkward defining separate variables?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for:

`Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>`

**Docs:**

[Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt)

[CSSStyleDeclaration](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.cssstyledeclaration.html)

Comment: This works inside the typescript but in the <template> it refuses to accept it.

     runtime-dom.d.ts(411, 3): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>'

Comment: You cant use any types on runtime. Can you please give an example where this might be needed? @GeeWhizBang

Answer (score 2):

You can do it elegantly using an interface and generics like this:

```js
interface MyData {
  strokeWidth: number;
  style: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>;
  arrowStyle: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>;
}

const data = ref<MyData>({
  strokeWidth: 0.108,
  style: {},
  arrowStyle: {},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an app example (it doesn't really do anything) but shows you how to set values on the fly for a style in typescript. If you don't set the type, vue3 stops on the getStyle(n).

```
 <template>
   <template v-for="n in data.count" :key="n">
     <div class="relative" :style="getStyle(n)"></div>
   </template>
 </template>
 <script>
 import { defineComponent, StyleValue } from 'vue';

 export default defineComponent({
   name: "MyApp",
   data() {
     return {
       count: 10,
       isVert: true,
       x: 10,
     };
  },
  methods: {
    getStyle(n: number): StyleValue {
      return this.data.isVert
        ? ({
          height: this.data.x / this.scale + 'px',
          top: this.data.x * n / this.scale + 'px'
        } as StyleValue)
        : ({
          width: this.data.x / this.scale + 'px',
          left: this.data.x * n / this.scale + 'px'
        } as StyleValue)
    },
  },
});
</script>
```